# Connect medical device to Android application using Bluetooth with A&D Medical devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

I am developing an Android app which pairs, connects and read the readings from the medical devices via Bluetooth, i am supporting various devices which works great but the two devices from the A&D Medicals are not connecting to get the readings after pairing. Devices are:
A&D Blood Pressure UA-767PBT and A&D Weight Scale UC-321PBT devices.

If anyone has done this or any help for me please let me know.
I am developing for:
Nexus series and Samsung Galaxy and Notes Tab and devices.

Comment: Have you ever found anything?

Comment: No Not Yet, What i observes is, The Master devices get affective while continuous threads to connect with slave devices are running like for NONIN 9560BT, MyGlucoHeath or any other, And as soon as these threads stopped the Master devices starts working.

Comment: I got one reply over my another account which states: You can't be listening and connecting simultaneously, instead of this only one state either listening or connecting the devices will be maintained. Just ask for the documentation if written over any forum or site.

Comment: Thanks for getting back @jitain we got the documentation from the Asia representatives but it's only a 2 page PDFs describing the data structure. Nothing too useful really.

Comment: I am able to Pair, Connect the A&D Devices [Master], but when i have slave devices for which i am continuously trying to connect after some interval during each fails, blocks Master devices to get connected. For this reason i have got one response as i have mentioned above. Now i just keep listening for a connection only, and try to connect only when user presses for a particular slave device. By using this now A&D Devices always connects to my app.

Comment: @jitain sharma : I am working on same A&D BP device.I am able to pair and collect data sent from device.But my app getting IOexeption after reading very first data from device.My app is not able to read continuous data sent by BP:UA-767PBT device.

Comment: @Abhi : How do you communicate with BP device?
Do you Open all channel every time or 1st time you open all channel and then save particular channel when communicate and after  you particular channel open and communicate.

Comment: Make sure that related Thread is completed or not?

Comment: Im trying to build an application in android to read some devices. I havent found much information about it. I wrote to A&D Medical and they are taking a while to get back to me.

Any one with example code or functional example reading the devices using the PHD HDP.

Thank you.

Comment: For those models you need to cache which port you had open when you got your first incoming connection.  The devices will ONLY attempt to connect at that port.  You'll need to hack in some  reflection to open a specific port on the bluetooth stack vs just opening a normal BT service.